# New web project

Tags: javascript, html, css

What do you think of http://websilon.org/? Are there things that can be improved? Is there something missing? See the source of the webpages for code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
<title>Websilon - Mathematical Knowledge Base</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="websilon, mathematics, math, knowlegde" />
<meta name="description" content="Websilon - Mathematical knowledge base" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en" />
<meta name="rating" content="safe for kids" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Websilon.org" />
<meta name="publisher" content="Websilon.org" />
<meta name="author" content="Websilon.org" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">  
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/page/1.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=yes;" />
<script src="/module/jquery/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" /></script>
<script src="/module/jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" /></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/module/jquery/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$","$"]]}
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/module/mathjax/MathJax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-28191597-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
.menu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu .content {
    width: 98%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 1%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.menu .content button {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 80%;
}

.menu ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50px;
    border-top: 0;
    font-size: 90%;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #252525;
}

.menu ul li a:active,
.menu ul li a:hover,
.menu ul li a:link,
.menu ul li a:visited,
.menu ul li {
    padding: 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AFAFAF;
}

.menu ul li {
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li:hover > a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
    background-color: #0B5ED9;
}

.menu ul li a {
    display: block;
}

.menu > li a:active,
.menu > li a:hover,
.menu > li a:link,
.menu > li a:visited,
.menu > li {
    font-size: 120%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.menu > li:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

.menu > li {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}

hr {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-bottom: 0;
}</style>

<script>
function TopMenu(selector) {

    var mainClass = this;
    var environment = selector;

    $(selector).css('z-index', 999999);

    $(window).scroll(function(e) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 0) {
            $(selector).css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0'
            });
        } else {
            $(selector).css({
                position: 'static'
            });
        }
    });

    $(selector).css('display', 'none');

    $(selector).ready(function() {
        if (typeof(mainClass.onLoad) == 'function') {
            mainClass.onLoad($(this));
        }
        $(selector).css('display', 'block');
    });

    /**
     * Get the height of the menu.
     *
     * @return  Menu height (int, pixels)
     */
    this.getHeight = function() {
        return parseInt($(selector).outerHeight());
    }

}</script>

<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Me</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://websilon.org/users/1/kevin/">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="/user/edit/">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user/logout/">Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Talk</a>
<ul>
        <li><a href="/talk/">Discussions</a></li>
    <li><a href="/talk/create/">New discussion</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Knowledge</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/kb/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="/kb/create/">Create</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<script>
TopMenu('.menu');
</script>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Websilon.org</h1>

            <p>
            Websilon is an open knowledge platform. It's a dynamic study environment. Books are static; if there is new knowledge, it will take a while before you can read it in books.
            </p>
            <p>
            Now we are in developing stage. You can partly use it and share some knowledge. If you would like to join or give ideas, please visit the <a href="/talk/view/1">Development</a> discussion.
            </p>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't mix up html, css and javascript. Put the css and javascript into separate files and externally reference them from the html files, this will:

1. clean up your html files
2. allow the browser to cache the css and javascript so the files don't have to be re-downloaded for each page visit in your site

Don't use `<a>` elements if you don't want to link something:

```
<li><a href="#">Talk</a>
```

Instead, I'd suggest to link to */talk/*, or, if that is not reasonable, use the `<span>` tag. Links to `#` are to use when you want to link to the top of the current page.

Comment: Thanks :). Problem is that these pages are auto-generated by Codeigniter and my view files. So seperating the Javascript/CSS files will be hard. And those links; when you visit the website with a smartphone, and you touch the menu button, then you will go to that page, right? So they will not be able to see the submenu that now will appear.

Comment: Then don't use `<a>`. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

On top of what Yogu said, I would also recommend moving you move as many of the `<script>` references to the bottom of your page just before your ending body tag. This will ensure that your view/html data loads before your Javascript, essentially speeding up the time it takes the user's browser to appear to load the page.

***Edit:** ANeves is correct, this method has been surpassed by asyncronously loading script files via such scripts as [yepnopejs](http://www.yepnopejs.com)

Comment: I disagree, instead of booting scripts to the end of pages we should link to external files and use the `async` and `defer` attributes of the script tag: http://developers.whatwg.org/scripting-1.html#the-script-element

Comment: You're correct, my answer has been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Not much more to say but, I only see ul-elements using the menu-class.

Is this really supposed to work? If not, then you can remove some excessive CSS.

```
.menu ul li
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add some exceptions to better deal with ie, such as using Chrome Frame:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})</script>
```

or

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!-- Consider adding an manifest.appcache: h5bp.com/d/Offline -->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
```